# TFS 2010 Map to shared folder

Tags: tfs

What are the impacts when everyone's mapping to the same shared folder in Visual Studio Team Explorer? Is it advisable? What would you suggest when developers are not supposed to save source code in their local drive(C:) since multiple users accessing the same PC across multiple shift. What's the best practice in order to protect the source code?

**User 1:**

```
Old Local Path: Not Mapped 
New Local Path: \\DevelopmentServer1\CookBook
```

**User 2:**

```
Old Local Path: Not Mapped
New Local Path: \\DevelopmentServer1\CookBook
```

**User 3:**

```
Old Local Path: Not Mapped
New Local Path: \\DevelopmentServer1\CookBook
```

Answer (score 0):

you should definately not use a shared folder for workspace mapping. TFS has no idea that this folder is the same on different computers and all changes will be messed up. If your developers are sharing a computer you can use a public workspace on the computer and they will be allowed to continue work that the last one left out. If you are concerned about theft of the computer you should either encrypt harddrive or set up a vmware/hyperv cluster where they have access to virtual machines for development.